# Safari unexpectedly crashes

Tags: safari, macos-big-sur

For the past two weeks, my Safari keeps crashing.

The crash report highlighted:

```
 <UnifiedTabBarButton: 0x7f9a893343f0>: invalid parameter not satisfying: isfinite(newOrigin.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

We solved it by deleting the following file:

/Users/**YourAccountName**/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist

Afterwards we needed to restart the macOS, otherwise Safari had no connection to any server.

We found the used .plist file by searching after all files containing the name "com.apple.Safari" and sorted after the date of the last change. We used the program "Find Any File" for this task.

Comment: the file has to be deleted from the terminal in the recovery mode